# RDLC report, generate a Pivot chart

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have the following data table format generated from SQL. Users can select which car models to be populated in the graph. There will be different number of Car models appearing in different reports. So there will be variable number of line charts appearing in the graph.(One line for one car model series)

> ```
>           Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
> Honda     12  17  24  18  30  13
> Toyota    15  20  10  15  30  40
> Yamaha    30  25  30  15  13  40
> Suzuki    35  15  13  40  45  45
> Nissan    15  35  40  40  50  50
> Kia       13  21  23  15  25  30
> Mazda     25  25  30  32  15  40
> ```

[image]
How can I create a graph like this with RDLC reports?

Comment: i think you can try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252128%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Are you able to get the unpivoted data from SQL? To even start thinking about the chart one would need three columns; model, month, sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using series groups in rdlc charting. The chart data source should be structured like this.

> ```
> Brand     Month   Value
>
> Honda     Jan     10
> Honda     Feb     15
> Honda     Mar     20
> Toyota    Jan     20
> Toyota    Feb     21
> Toyota    Mar     22
> Yamaha    Jan     10
> Yamaha    Feb     11
> Yamaha    Mar     12
> ```

Add "Value" column as chart Values.
Add "Month" column as chart Categories.
Add "Brand" column as chartSeries Groups.