# Sum of Each Column in Pie Chart in RDLC report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

In RDLC report I've got 3 columns in a dataset with integer values. I want to show sum of each column, in a one pie chart. I tried putting Sum(field1), Sum(field2) ... in values  but it doesn't work correctly and creates several series. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get series on separate column. One person already answered this.
[Generate Report with different series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609124/rdlc-report-generate-a-pivot-chart)